# How to plot multiple xarray DataArray objects into one figure using the xarray plotting capability?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have the following xarray DataSet with 3 dimensions (`time`, `latitude`, `longitude`) and 2 variables (`__xarray_dataarray_variable__`, `regions`). The `regions` variable can be either nan, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 indicating the region Id for the lat/lon. The `__xarray_dataarray_variable__` variable is of integer.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                        (latitude: 106, longitude: 193, time: 92)
Coordinates:
  * latitude                       (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.9
  * longitude                      (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 ... 150.0
  * time                           (time) datetime64[ns] 1972-01-01 ... 2017-07-01
Data variables:
    __xarray_dataarray_variable__  (time, latitude, longitude) int32 dask.array<shape=(92, 106, 193), chunksize=(2, 106, 193)>
    regions                        (latitude, longitude) float64 nan nan ... nan
```

I would like plot a figure which contains 6 lines and where the Y axis is the spatial mean value of `__xarray_dataarray_variable__` and X axis is the `time`. Each line is for one region Id.

```
da = ds["__xarray_dataarray_variable__"]

# Region 0
da_region_0 = da.where(ds.regions == 0)
da_region_0_mean = da_region.mean(['longitude', 'latitude'])  # Get spatial mean

# We can follow the example to get da for region 1 - region 5.
... ...
p_mean = da_region_0_mean.plot.line(x='time')  # This is only plotting a figure for each region but not all 6 regions.
```

How can I plot one single figure that contains lines for all 6 regions instead of individual figures for each using the xarray plot capability?

Comment: Did you try creating a figure and supplying its axis to each of your line plots? That should help if you want to overlay multiple xarray plots in one figure

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are looking for.  This is the way that I would approach it.  I'll set up some data in the style of yours first:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = np.random.random((6, 3, 11))
da = xr.DataArray(data, dims=['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], name='foo')

region_data = np.random.choice(range(6), size=(6, 3))
region = xr.DataArray(region_data, dims=['longitude', 'latitude'], name='region')

ds = xr.merge([da, region])
```

This Dataset, `ds`, looks like:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (latitude: 3, longitude: 6, time: 11)
Dimensions without coordinates: latitude, longitude, time
Data variables:
    foo      (longitude, latitude, time) float64 0.7016 0.1519 ... 0.1446 0.2396
    region   (longitude, latitude) int64 5 1 1 5 0 1 0 0 2 3 0 4 4 3 3 1 2 1
```

To compute the regional means, we can first stack the longitude and latitude dimensions of the Dataset:

```py
stacked = ds.stack(xy=('longitude', 'latitude'))
```

This will enable us to easily use `groupby` to group by region number when computing the mean:

```py
regional_means = stacked.foo.groupby(stacked.region).mean('xy')
```

To plot, we can use [`xarray.DataArray.plot.line`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.line.html) along with the `hue` keyword argument to produce a single panel with time series lines for each region:

```py
lines = regional_means.plot.line(hue='region', add_legend=False)
labels = range(6)
plt.legend(lines, labels, ncol=2, loc='lower right')
```

Here we have opted to create our own legend to give us as much control as possible over its position and format.  This produces a plot like this:

[image: Multi-line plot]

More line plotting examples can be found [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#multiple-lines-showing-variation-along-a-dimension).